# Equivalence of relative and (reduced) homology for arbitrary pairs

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

I could not find my mistake in the following argument, though I know it is wrong. This is more like a "Q&A", since there is nothing to "prove" in the positive sense. Here it goes:

> For an arbitrary pair (X, A) with A non-empty, we know that for positive $n$
>
> $H_n(X, A) \simeq H_n(X \cup CA - x, CA - x) \simeq H_n(X \cup CA, CA) \simeq H_n(X \cup CA) \simeq H_n(X/A)$

where $CA$ is attached to $X$ by $[(a, 0)] \simeq a \in X$, $x$ is the tip of the cone, and the iso's are by: homotopy invariance, excision, long sequence and again homotopy invariance by the following, which is my concern:

> Let $f : X \cup CA \to X/A, x \mapsto x, CA \mapsto [A]$ and $g : X/A \to X \cup CA, x \mapsto x, [A] \mapsto [(a, 1)]$ for any $a \in A$.
> Then $fg = 1$ and $gf \simeq 1$ by $h_t : X \cup CA \to X \cup CA, x \mapsto x, [(a, 1 - s)] \mapsto [(a, 1 - ts)]$, $0 \le t \le 1$.

What did I do wrong in the above? I would also like to know what *is* true (Hatcher hints that this leads somewhere, but it is not clear from the phrasing.) This matters in the economy of that chapter.

Comment: Is $g$ continuous?

Comment: @Christoph: The open set of $X \cup CA$ being... ? Is this guesswork left to me or you suggest that it's too trivial?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The point $[(a,1)]\in X\cup CA$ is the top of the attached cone, it has the open neighborhood $$ U = \left\{\, [(a,t)]\, \middle|\, t>\frac 1 2\,\right\}.$$
Now the preimage under $g$ is $g^{-1}(U) = \{[A]\}$, since every $x\notin A$ is mapped outside the cone. Thus, for $g$ to be continuous, you need the one-point set $\{[A]\}$ to be open in $X/A$ which is equivalent to $A$ being open in $X$.

Comment: Also, $\{[(a,1)]\}$ is closed, so $A$ had to be closed as well.

Comment: @StefanHamcke You're right, so $A$ needs to be a union of connected components for $g$ to be continuous. — By the way, did you know we're taking the same course on homotopy theory? ;-)

Comment: Yes, I'm aware of that ;-) Did you cover the cellular approximation thing on Tuesday? I couldn't be there

Comment: Yeah, found it out in the meantime, but thanks! So this means that (usually) $X$ is not path-connected. That's sad. Maybe I'm missing something... why does Hatcher state that it is true for "arbitrary" pairs ?!

Comment: @ChindeaFilip He doesn't. He says that homology of a pair can be expressed as reduced absolute homology by $H_n(X,A) \cong \widetilde H_n(X\cup CA)$ for arbitrary pairs, but we don't always have $\widetilde H_n(X\cup CA)\cong \widetilde H_n(X/A)$.